# Using `mathbb` fonts from other packages

Tags: fonts, math-mode, xetex, mathpazo, mathspec

I am currently using a combination of `mathpazo` and `mathspec` for my maths typesetting. To be specific, my preamble contains the following:

```
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{mathspec}

\usepackage{xltxtra,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}

\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Palatino Linotype}
\setsansfont{Optima}
\setmonofont{Consolas}
\setmathsf{Optima}
\setmathfont(Greek){Palatino Linotype}

\exchangeforms{phi}
```

However, I would like the option of using, say, the AMS blackboard bold fonts for `mathbb`, or the ones provided by STIX (or any other Unicode maths font) instead of the ones provided by `mathpazo`. So far nothing I've tried with `\setmathbb` has worked.

I have a similar problem with `\setmathcal`, and I notice that if I use `calrsfs` instead of `mathrsfs` there is no effect whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

I'd go directly to **unicode-math**:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % loads amsmath that should go before unicode-math
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Palatino Linotype}
\setsansfont{Optima}
\setmonofont{Consolas}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
```

Asana Math is based on the MathPaZo fonts.

If you really need brackets and parentheses from the MathPaZo fonts, it's doable:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{brackets}       {OT1}{zplm}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{brackets}{bold}     {OT1}{zplm}{b}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{largebrackets}  {OMX}{zplm}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largebrackets}{bold}{OMX}{zplm}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{(}{\mathopen} {brackets}{"28}{largebrackets}{"00}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{)}{\mathclose}{brackets}{"29}{largebrackets}{"01}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{[}{\mathopen} {brackets}{"5B}{largebrackets}{"02}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{]}{\mathclose}{brackets}{"5D}{largebrackets}{"03}
```

For the Knuth calligraphic font, add

```
\setmathfont[range={\mathcal,\mathbfcal},StylisticSet=1]{XITS Math}
```

For a "better" `\vDash` symbol, add

```
\setmathfont[range=\vDash]{XITS Math}
```

The "not belonging to" symbol should *always* be specified with `\notin` rather than with `\not\in`.

Finally, for the AMS blackboard bold:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{AMSb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}
\protected\def\mathbb#1{{\mathchar\numexpr256*\symAMSb+`#1\relax}}
```

Comment: The results are ugly (particularly all the brackets), and I would have to set the calligraphic range to something else since I want to use both rsfs-like and eucal-like symbols.

Comment: Add `\setmathfont[range={\mathcal,\mathbfcal}]{Neo Euler}` The font can be downloaded at https://github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf; then `\mathscr` will give the rsfs font, `\mathcal` the Euler Calligraphic. What's the problem with brackets?

Comment: The brackets (all types — round, square, curly, etc.) are generally too large (e.g. when enclosing symbols with ascenders or descenders) and spaced unusually compared to the typesetting of mathpazo. Some of the symbols are also particularly ugly, such as `\vDash`. `\not\in` is entirely broken, requiring the use of `\notin` instead. The command you suggested isn't what I meant — I want the default `\mathcal` font, not the Euler font. Thanks for the link, however.

Comment: Thank you for your edit. However, this seems very cumbersome. Isn't there a way to do the reverse and use unicode-math only for, say, `\mathbb`, and mathspec for the rest?

Comment: I followed your method to use AMS blackboard with Pagella Math. However it doesn't work with $\hat\mathbb{Z}$. The error is `` Internal error: bad native font flag in `map_char_to_glyph' ``. The same error appears [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63244/). Is there any better workaround? Thank you.

Comment: @Unknown You have a syntax error: `\hat{\mathbb{Z}}`

Comment: @egreg, I'm sorry that I made the mistake. I redefined the `\mathbb{Z}` as `\bbZ`, so I usually use `\hat\bbZ` rather than `\hat{\bbZ}` by omitting the brackets. I just found [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82329/). It maybe helpful for others who have the same problem as mine. Thank you!

Comment: @Unknown It would be better to type `\hat{\bbZ}` anyway.

Comment: @egreg, sorry to bother you again. After done some tests, I found that the problem was not caused by brackets. In your code, `range={\mathcal,\mathbfcal}` was set (to get a minimal example, I only copied this line). But I load a font without setting the range. In the former case, both $\hat\bbZ$ and $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ work. But in my situation, neither of them works. So I think maybe I need to set the range manually so as to skip some range.

Comment: @Unknown The best is to ask a new question with an example of code that causes the error.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/214570/9848