# Parsing question: Do curly braces affect LaTeX compilation time?

Tags: compiling, parsing, performance

I have an old and slow computer and long LaTeX files. When typing I prefer to use `\frac 1{x}` instead of `\frac{1}{x}` or `x_i` instead of `x_{i}`.

Does the presence or omission of curly braces in these instances affect the compilation time in any way? If so in which way?

Comment: Well to begin with, `x_mn` is not the same as `x_{mn}` but with regards to the compilation I cannot say much.

Comment: A simple experiment using `time` with and without braces for 60 simple expressions shows that the `real` and `user` times increase with braces (from 0.195s to 0.210s and from 0.176s to 0.188s). The `sys` time remains equal (0.020s).

Comment: I would guess the answer is "yes they do, but not by any appreciable amount". One way to test would be using the PGF benchmarking library.

Comment: You might speed up workflow (compiling, but also editing) by splitting your document into pieces to `\import` or `\include`. Then work on one piece at a time, with separate compilation, perhaps with `\includeonly` or commenting in/out lines in `main.tex`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, what are `real`, `user` and `sys`? Where could I find more about?

Comment: @Sigur: take a look at [What do `real`, `user` and `sys` mean in the output of `time`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556405/what-do-real-user-and-sys-mean-in-the-output-of-time1).

Comment: The version without the braces are an (unreported) syntax error, so you shouldn't use those. The time differences are likely to be orders of magnitute less than the time taken to post the question:-) See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82329/how-bad-for-tex-is-omitting-braces-even-if-the-result-is-the-same/82337#82337

Comment: Yes, but unless you are using a computer made before TeX was developed you won't notice any difference.

Comment: I tried typesetting `$\frac12$` one million times getting a user time of 8.69 seconds, while `$\frac{1}{2}$`  the same number of times takes 8.81 seconds. This is what I call a negligible difference; the latter syntax is clearer.

Comment: @PaulGessler I did; if you upvote the answer now, it won't affect my rep. `;-)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The version without the braces is processed a tiny bit faster than the version with braces. Typesetting one million times `$\frac12$` required 8.69 seconds, while a million `$\frac{1}{2}$` took 8.81 seconds. This is what I call a negligible difference; the latter syntax is clearer.