# Usage of the curly brackets

Tags: math-mode, braces

I have noticed today that the LaTeX would compile regardless if I put curly brackets or not. What I mean is this: I would usually write in maths mode `\frac{1}{2}` however latex also compiles if I write `\frac 1 2` i.e. without using the curly brackets. Of course it gives me error if I don't give two arguments and just type something like `\frac 1`.

It saves me a lot of effort to write without using the curly brackets in particular because they are located in such a bad position in the keyboard and require either Alt+Ctrl or AltGr. What are the other advantages/disadvantages of writing without curly brackets.

Comment: Try `\frac 12 4`

Comment: Regardless? :D:D Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Use a US keyboard - layout -- then `{}` are quite easy to type. And the advantage is a much clearer syntax to have `{}`, especially when looking through code written by others

Comment: @Au101: \frac 12 4 would clearly not work it would typeset 1/2 4. If I wanted to write 12/4 then I should use \frac{12} 4.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I don't understand what is so funny.

Comment: @gonenc you can do all sorts of things eg `$x^\frac12$` works like `$x^{\frac{1}{2}}$` but it makes it much harder to read and if you do this for long enough you will one day forget and change `x^9` to `x^10` (everybody has done this:-)  and it makes your document much harder to parse with any system that isn't a full tex engine (so most tex to html converters for example)

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155226/parsing-question-do-curly-braces-affect-latex-compilation-time

Comment: @gonenc: never mind ...

Answer (score 1):

The curly braces are needed for arguments longer than 1 character, e.g. `\frac{10}{17}`.

If you write `\frac1017`, this will be interpreted as `\frac{1}{0}17`.

Comment: I know that it typeset that way. The question is would it be of disadvantage if I write eg.`\frac 1 2` instead of `\frac{1}{2}`

Comment: @gonenc No, it's the same, but it's much less readable.

Comment: Most people would discourage the use of `\frac12` as it will cause an error if you change the expression to 11/2 later on and forget to add the braces to form `\frac{11}{2}`. Nevertheless, I use it quite often, because it is faster and simpler. The same holds for `x^2` vs. `x^{2}`.