# How to add upper/lower fence + outliers to a box plot?

Tags: pgfplots, boxplot

I'm trying to create a box & whiskers plot that includes the upper & lower fence, and the outliers. My current plot looks like this (minus all the labeling):

[image: a boxplot that has only the Q1, median, Q2, upper, & lower whiskers graphed]

```latex
\documentclass [12pt, letterpaper] {article}

\usepackage {pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset {compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary {statistics}

\begin {document}

\begin {center}
\begin {tikzpicture}
\begin {axis} [
    xmin = 15,
    xmax = 35,
    xtick = {15, 20, 25, 30, 35},
    ytick = \empty,
    width = 10cm,
    height = 5cm,
]
\addplot + [
    boxplot prepared = {
        median = 25.5,
        upper quartile = 27,
        lower quartile = 23,
        upper whisker = 31,
        lower whisker = 17,
    },
] coordinates {};
\end {axis}
\end {tikzpicture}
\end {center}

\end {document}
```

The problem is I can't figure out how to add the upper fence, lower fence, and my outliers; I'd need my graph to look more-so like this:

[image: a box plot that has the Q1, median, Q1, upper whisker & lower whisker marked, but this time includes the upper fence, lower fence, and some outliers (with everything being labeled)]

Comment: +1: Nice code example. Is there a reason why there are so many spaces between commands and arguments, e. g. `\end {center}`?

Comment: The reason there's so many spaces is probably since I just yanked this table out of the .tex file I was writing, and removed all the data that was irrelevant to this question. Also I generally prefer to over-use white space since it makes things slightly more readable (personally speaking, at least)

Comment: I see, there seems to be no problem with that: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202020

Comment: I have provided a manual solution and some references on how I calculated it. Maybe some of the better experts will provide an automated solution.

Answer (score 2):

- I provide a **very manual solution** because I am not skilled enough for a more automated solution.
- I calculate the position of the fences manually [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot) (as of 2022-01-30), see citation block below.
- Then I draw a dashed line manually.
- Watch out, the code must be before `\end{axis}`!
- You can use `\draw[dashed, blue] (17, 0.6) -- (17, 1.4);` if you want
  to change the color.
- I commented `%ytick = \empty` out, in order to see which values I need for the y positions (0.6 and 1.4).

> The same data set can also be made into a box-plot through a different
> approach as shown in Figure 3. This time the boundaries of the
> whiskers are found within the **1.5 IQR value**. From above the **upper**
> **quartile (Q3**), a distance of **1.5 times the IQR** is measured out and a
> whisker is drawn up to the largest observed data point from the
> dataset that falls within this distance. Similarly, a distance of **1.5**
> **times the IQR** is measured out below the **lower quartile (Q1)** and a
> whisker is drawn down to the lowest observed data point from the
> dataset that falls within this distance. All other observed data
> points outside the boundary of the whiskers are plotted as outliers.

[image]
*(Source: https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-boxplots-5e2df7bcbd51)*

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [
    xmin = 15,
    xmax = 35,
    xtick = {15, 20, 25, 30, 35},
    %ytick = \empty,
    width = 10cm,
    height = 5cm,
]
\addplot+[
    boxplot prepared = {
        median = 25.5,
        upper quartile = 27, % Q3
        lower quartile = 23, % Q1
        upper whisker = 31,
        lower whisker = 17,
    },
] coordinates {};
% https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot
% IQR = 27 - 23 = 4
% 1.5 * IQR = 6
% Lower Fence = Q1 - 1.5 * IQR = 17
% Upper Fence = Q3 + 1.5 * IQR = 33
\draw[dashed] (17, 0.6) -- (17, 1.4);
\draw[dashed] (33, 0.6) -- (33, 1.4);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]