# Linguex and Tipa

Tags: fonts, errors, linguistics, tipa, linguex

The numbering of the sentences shows as underlined dots when using      \ag. \a. \b.     of     linguex     and     tipa     .     \bg.     works fine but starts numbering from (a.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage[main=english,italian,spanish,portuguese,catalan]{babel}
%babel has problems with french - tried frenchle does't work either
\usepackage{harvard}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\section{Catalan}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text (English)

\ex. \label{cat2}
\ag. en Joan t\'e m\'es vaques que en Pere. (NP-comparison)\\
D John have.3SG more cows than D Peter\\
John has more cows than Peter. \cite{Hualde2002}
\bg. t' estimo m\'es que la Maria.\\
CL.2s love more that the Mary\\
I love you more than Mary. \cite{Hualde2002}
\bg. en Joan \'es m\'es alt que la Maria. (AdjP-Comparison)\\
D John is more tall that D Maria\\
John is taller than Mary \cite{Hualde2002}

\section{English}

\ex. \a. This is an English example. 
\b. This is an English example.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Load `linguex` after `tipa`. However, this might cause malfunctions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not actually with the `tipa` package itself, but with basically any font package you would load. The problem is caused by the fact that `linguex` defines a `\b.` and and `\c.` macro, but both of these are used as diacritic commands (`\b` puts a macron under a character, and `\c` puts a cedilla. So loading the font package after `linguex` removes the `linguex` definitions.

The problem, however, is indeed solved by loading the font package before loading `linguex`. Since `linguex` defines these macros as delimited macros requiring a `.` after them, no interaction will arise with the font commands provided you wrap their arguments in braces. (`{}`).  (See [How bad for TeX is omitting braces {}, even if the result is the same?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82329/2693) for more on why this is generally a good idea.)

Here are two minimal example documents that show exactly how this works. Notice that in the first example, the first two sublist labels are a `.` with a macron underneath, but the third (made with `\c.`) is a `.` with a cedilla under it.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
% linguex examples fail
\ex.\label{1}
\a. An example
\b. Another example
\c. Another example

% font commands work unbraced
\Large\centering
\b a \c c 
\end{document}
```

[image: output sample 1]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}
% linguex examples work
\ex.\label{1}
\a. An example
\b. Another example

% font commands only work braced
\Large\centering
\b{a} \c{c} 
% font commands DON’T work unbraced (uncomment to produce error)
%\b a \c c 
\end{document}
```

[image: output of sample 2]

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late here, but the answer by Alan Munn was super helpful for me, so I'd like to chip in with an extra tip.

Using `linguex`, I had the abc examples come out wrong in the same way that the original question described. The thing is, I already had `linguex` below `tipa` as suggested above. However, the note about other font packages helped direct my further search -- turns out that, at least for me, I also had to have the `babel` package above `linguex`. Hope it helps to someone!