# Which way should I type a fraction?

Tags: typography, fractions, inline

When I type a fraction, I always use form `\dfrac{m}{n}`. For example: `$\dfrac{1}{2}$` and `$\dfrac{1}{23}$`. Somewhere, I saw that, instead of  `$\dfrac{1}{2}$` it was type `$\dfrac 12$` and `$\dfrac1{23}$`. What is the best way which I choose?

Comment: Inline, it's best to use $m/n$.  In a displayed equation, it depends, but in most cases $\frac{m}{n}$ suffices.

Comment: No, remove what you saw from your memory. :) While the usage `\dfrac nd` or `\dfrac n{dd}` holds, stick to something consistent, so use `\dfrac{n}{d}`, *always*.

Comment: why `\dfrac` which makes an over-sized fraction unsuitable for inline math why not `\frac{1}{2}` ?

Comment: You might be interested in [How bad for TeX is omitting braces `{}`, even if the result is the same?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82329)

Comment: I'll oppose what @Werner says; I don't use braces if both arguments to `\frac` are one token. However, I don't mix the two in one fraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stick to a consistent usage, supplying parameters to the macro using braces. As such, the best way is to use

```
\frac{<num>}{<denom>}
```

which clearly identifies the `num`erator and `denom`inator.

---

(La)TeX, like other programming languages, allows one to bend the rules on occasion. However, stick to proper use of the language; you don't gain anything by dropping proper argument deliniation.

As an analogy, things may *sound* the same (phonetically), but their meaning can be completely different if not used properly:

[image]