# Try to use AMS blackboard bold font together with TexGyrePagella

Tags: accents, unicode-math, blackboard

I am trying to use AMS blackboard bold font together with TG Pagella Math in the way given in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21742/9848). But I got the error

```
! Internal error: bad native font flag in `map_char_to_glyph'
```

Example (xelatex):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\DeclareSymbolFont{AMSb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}
\protected\def\mathbb#1{{\mathchar\numexpr256*\symAMSb+`#1\relax}}

\begin{document}
  $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$
\end{document}
```

It seems that there is a similar question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63244/internal-error-bad-native-font-flag-xelatex-fontspec-newtxmath-libertine). I would like to know whether there are some better workaround to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Ugly workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\protected\def\mathbb#1{\text{\usefont{U}{msb}{m}{n}#1}}

\begin{document}
  $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}_{\mathbb{Z}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That destroys the proper math spacing!

Comment: @MaxNoe What do you mean?

Comment: Compare `$\mathbb{XYZ}$` with and without your command.

Comment: @MaxNoe Did you try `\mathbb{XYZ}` with `pdflatex`? The spacing is the same as you get with my code. The TeX Gyre math fonts add spacing around blackboard bold letters, AMS doesn't.